# ElfinderClient Server API Arabic langage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, elfinder

Am using the Elfinder Client Server API 2.0, and i have some folders in Arabic Language, When i use the command:

```
    connector.php?cmd=open&target=l1_Mg
```

i called the directory in the target by its hash, so all files are listed expected the files in Arabic languages.

Also i tried to change the json_encode inside the class elfinder like below:

```
    JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES
```

but still the same result

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be set configs [`encoding`](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options-2.1#encoding) and [`locale`](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options-2.1#locale-1) correctly, to elFinder connects to the file system of the character encoding other than UTF-8.

It require elFinder 2.1.x.

```
$opts = array(
    'roots'  => array(
        array(
            'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem',
            'path'   => '/path/to/files/',
            'URL'    => 'http://localhost/to/files/',
            'encoding' => 'YOUR ENCOFDING',
            'locale' => 'YOUR LOCALE'
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: I tried the Encoding UTF-8 but still the same issue, am not able to see the arabic listed files

Concerning the Locale, could you please help me how to set it ? 
Thanks

Comment: Which is your server encoding? Please set that value.

Comment: Please set the appropriate value because treatment with iconv.

Comment: I found Iconv List of Encodings. https://gist.github.com/hakre/4188459

> ARABIC ASMO-708 ECMA-114 ISO-8859-6 ISO-IR-127 ISO8859-6 ISO_8859-6 ISO_8859-6:1987 CSISOLATINARABIC

Comment: Maybe 'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-6' ?

Comment: Not working yet, i tried it and i tried different ENCODING, but still arabic file names not appearing

Answer (score 0):

```
$opts = array(
// 'debug' => true,

'roots' => array(
    array(
        'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',           // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
        'path'          => '../files/',                 // path to files (REQUIRED)
        'URL'           => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
        'uploadDeny'    => array('all'),                // All Mimetypes not allowed to upload
        'uploadAllow'   => array('image', 'text/plain'),// Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` allowed to upload
        'uploadOrder'   => array('deny', 'allow'),      // allowed Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` only
        'accessControl' => 'access' ,  
        'locale' => 'Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256'
    )
)
);

// run elFinder
$connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts));
$connector->run();
```